# How to write Robolectric (2.3) test using database

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, robolectric

Due to last release of Robolectic to version 2.3, it's written that (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases):

> Robolectric now uses a real implementation of SQLite instead of a collection of shadows and fakes. Tests can now be written to verify real database behavior.

I haven't found any "How to" documentation.
I'd like to know how should I implement test on e.g. Activity using SQLiteDatabase query. Where should I put .db file so a test uses it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to put the .db file under `src/test/resources/` folder.

For example, `sample.db`

Then in your unit test setUp() call:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    String filePath = getClass().getResource("/sample.db").toURI().getPath();

    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
        (new File(filePath)).getAbsolutePath(), 
        null, 
        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

   // perform any db operations you want here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example how to test database, oprations.

```
    // just a wrapper for the content values map
    Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
    agenda.setName("MyAgenda");
    agenda.setDate("current date");

    long rowId = agendaManager.insert(agenda); // the guy who makes database operations

    Cursor query = context.getContentResolver().query(AgendaProvider.AGENDA_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    assertThat(query.getCount()).isEqualTo(1);
    query.moveToNext();
    Agenda dbAgenda = new Agenda(query);
    assertThat(dbAgenda.getRowId()).isPositive();
    assertThat(dbAgenda.getRowId()).isEqualTo(rowId);
    assertThat(dbAgenda.getName()).isEqualTo(agenda.getName());
    assertThat(dbAgenda.getDate()).isEqualTo(agenda.getDate());
```

An more detailed example may be found here https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/blob/master/UnitTestsRobolectric/src/test/java/com/example/managers/AgendaManagerTest.java